# Django Change all other Boolean fields except one

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-2.2

I have a model which has a boolean field:

```
class Library(SocialLinksModelMixin):
    """
    Represents book shelves and places where people have / leave books.
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(...)
    is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

User can have multiple Libraries and I would like to allow setting the main one to ease the flow in the app.

What is the easiest way for switching only one Library is_main to True and all others to False (There is always only 1 Library for a user that is main)

I'm thinking about querying for all libraries and updating each and every one. Maybe there is another way to do that functionality?

Comment: It is a bit odd that this model is named `Library`. This means that each library points to *exactly one* user? Furthermore that the main library is the same for everyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the *primary key* of the `Library` to set the `is_main` to `True`, you can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Library.objects.filter(user=my_user).update(
    is_main=Q(pk=my_pk)
)
```

You might also want to enforce at database level that there can only be one `Library` with `is_main=True` *per* `user`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models import Q

class Library(SocialLinksModelMixin):
    """
    Represents book shelves and places where people have / leave books.
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=('user',), condition=Q(is_main=True), name='one_main_per_user')
        ]
```

Comment: This is super! Combining those 2 things should save me from updating every single user's library 'manually' ? I mean: Updating one library's is_main field to __True__ would set other Libraries' is_main to __False__?

Comment: @Hvitis: yes, for the same user, you can update all of its libraries with a single query.